# Find the area of ​the triangle EGB.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, plane-geometry

> Through the centroid $G$ of a triangle $ABC$, a secant line is drawn, cutting sides $AB$ and $BC$. On the straight line a point $E$ is considered. Calculate the area of ​​the triangle $EBG$ if the areas of the triangles $ECG$ and $AEG$ are $20$ and $30$ respectively.
> (Answer: $50$)

My progress:

I can't develop much..sorry.

[image: triangle with line through centroid]

I know $G$ is centroid :
$\therefore S_{\triangle ABG} = S_{\triangle AGC} = S_{\triangle BGC}.$

Also $\triangle AEG, \triangle EGC, \triangle BEG$ have the same base.

I don't see similarity of triangles.

The heights are different...

I didn't understand the function of the line

????

Comment: You have asked a very similar question in the past.

Comment: Do you know Menelaus' theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem

Comment: Pls drop perp from $A, B$ and $C$ to the secant. Can you see why the perp from $B$ is sum of perp from $A$ and $C$?

Comment: $BG$ extends to midpoint of $AC$ Sum of perp from $A$ and $C$ is equal to twice the perp from midpoint of $AC$. But that is equal to the perp from $B$

Comment: @MathLover  Thamks for hint..I undertood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be the midpoint of $AC$. Drop the perpendicular lines from $A,$ $B,$ $C$ and $D$ to $\overleftrightarrow{EG}$.

[image]

Since $DD'$ is the midline of trapezium $AA'C'C$,

$$DD'=\frac{AA'+CC'}2.$$

As $G$ is the centroid,

$$\frac{BB'}{DD'}=\frac{BG}{GD}=\frac21.$$

Therefore, $BB'=AA'+CC'.$

Thus, $[\triangle BEG]=[\triangle AEG]+[\triangle CEG].$

Comment: gratitude for resoution